# How to print long widgets consecutively

Tags: qt

At QT, I made the ui with QWidget. And I want to print the ui with my printer. But, The ui is too long to print on one page.(height is greater than the A4 size) I want continuous prints without newPage() function.

I use QPrinter and QPainter. But, The result I received was a cropped widget image. I don't want to use newPage() function.

```
QPrinter printer;
QPainter painter;

QPrintDialog printDialog(&printer);
if (printDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    painter.begin(&printer);
    ui->scrollArea->widget()->render(&painter);
}
```

I do not like to apply printer.newPage() manually to every ui.

Is there any option or code that prints automatically on the next page like MS Word?

Comment: Did you set Printer Layout and Page Size to correct values?

Comment: I didn't any Layout Page size setting. I use default. Do i set specific Layout and Page Size for A4 print?

Comment: Try to set page size and margins to A4 format. Take a look here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html and here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpagelayout.html If this won't work you will need to use newPage to break your widget...